# Link to Anchor Tag on Another Page Doesn't Work

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a wordpress site (not available to the public). I have a menu and within that menu, I have a link e.g. http://example.org/schedule/#x-content-band-1

Now, when I click that, nothing happens. The status bar at the bottom of my browser shows that URL (which is correct) but clicking on it does nothing. However if I right hand click and open up a new tab/window, then it opens up the page just fine

LINK

```
<a href="http://example.org/schedule/#x-content-band-1"><span>Speakers</span></a>
```

ANCHOR

```
<div id="x-content-band-1">...</div>
```

Comment: After more thought I doubt that my solution is your issue. Try clearing your browser cache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hyphens can be troublesome in cases where you have multiple similar IDs. Browsers tend to treat hyphenated URL components as separate words, so you may have several that appear identical.

Try underscores or camelCase, or make sure the substring before the first hyphen is unique.